# Microsoft Power Automate Wrong OAuth Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I created a Custom Connector with Microsoft Automate.

I need the Connector to get a OAuth Token v2 but get a v1 Token.

When I use the same configuration in Postman I get a v2 Token.

The application manifes has the entry "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2

[image: Connector Configuration]

[image: Postman Configuration]

Comment: Please try to embed images directly into question instead of giving links to it.

Comment: Try to change the application manifest: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMSsx.png

Comment: I checked that but the application manifest already had the entry.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re describing isn’t possible, the application where you’re requesting the token for dictates the token version.

It’s not described in your question, so I’m assuming that you have an app exposing the scope (with team.create) and have an other application that you are using to request a token?

Are you sure you are checking the right token?

Have you inspected the tokens at https://JWT.ms, be sure to check the audience (if it’s graph by accident, it will always be a v1 token)

And last note, why do you care about the token version? Shouldn’t really matter which one is used.